# Symfony/PHPUnit enable profiler in tests

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, profiler

I want to enable the symfony profiler for my tests,I followed this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html) but my profiler stay empty. I'm using PHPUnit 7.5.16, and Symfony 4.3.4 with PHP 7.2.19.
What should I add ?

```html
#web_profiler:
#    toolbar: false
#    intercept_redirects: false
#
#framework:
#    profiler: { collect: false }

web_profiler:
  toolbar: true
  intercept_redirects: false

framework:
#  profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
  # make tests slowest, but it s usefull in local,watch this doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/profiling.html
  profiler: { enabled: true, collect: true }
```

and in the setUp() method I have

```
parent::setUp();
$client = static::createClient();
$client->enableProfiler();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely also need:

```
framework:
    test: true
```

Since you are enabling the profile in the test, you don't need to do so with

```
framework:
   profiler: { enabled: true, ... # can be 'enabled: false', if you enable it in a test
```

My own config for the test environment is:

```
> bin/console -e test debug:config framework profiler

Current configuration for "framework.profiler"
==============================================

enabled: true
collect: false
only_exceptions: false
only_master_requests: false
dsn: 'file:%kernel.cache_dir%/profiler'
```

and `framework: test: true`. With this config, I've got a test environment that enables the profile, and checks for results in it.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you